# Unable to view JSON data from PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using MySQL and created 2 tables in it; `Users` and `Activity`. User table has following data:

[image]

For now I am using the above data only. I want this data to show in JSON format and then I will use it in my Android app. I have tried to convert it but I am getting the below result:

> ( ! ) Warning:
>   mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\MobileApp\index.php on line *18*
>   Call
>   Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0015134480{main}(  )...\index.php**:**0 20.0034141920getUserName(  )...\index.php**:**38 30.0034142272http://www.php.net/function.mysqli-query'
>   target='_new'>mysqli_query (  )...\index.php**:**18
>
> ( ! ) Warning:
>   mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null
>   given in D:\xampp\htdocs\MobileApp\index.php on line
>   *20* Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0015134480{main}(  )...\index.php**:**0 20.0034141920getUserName(  )...\index.php**:**38 30.0050142240http://www.php.net/function.mysqli-fetch-array'
>   target='_new'>mysqli_fetch_array (  )...\index.php**:**20

```
{"users":[]}
```

I have posted the above result in 3 steps so it can be clearly identified what mistake I am making.

Below is my PHP file:

```
require_once ('config.php');

function getUserName()
{
// array for json response
$response = array();
$response["users"] = array();

// Mysql select query
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Users");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    // temporary array to create single category
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp["Id"] = $row["Id"];
    $tmp["Name"] = $row["Name"];

    // push category to final json array
    array_push($response["Users"], $tmp);
}
// keeping response header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// echoing json result
echo json_encode($response);
}

getUserName();
```

And my config file:

```
<?php 
 define("HOST","localhost");
 define("DATABASE","app");
 define("USERNAME","root");
 define("PASSWORD","");

 $con=mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
 if(!$con){
    die("Database Connection Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 else{
  echo "Connection successful";
 }
```

I am getting ‘Connection successful’ from `config`.

I don't know what wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you use `mysqli_query`.

As said in error message `mysqli_query` expects two parameters. The first one will be the connection object and the second one, the query.

i.e. :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Users");
```

And then, build you json data like this with `json_encode()` php function.

```
require_once ('config.php');

function getUserName()
{
    // defines global since $con not in the scope of the function variables
    global $con;

    $response = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        // temporary array to create single category
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["Id"] = $row["Id"];
        $tmp["Name"] = $row["Name"];

        // build response array
        $response['users'][] = $tmp;
    }

    // convert $response array to json and return it
    return json_encode($response);
}

// get function return 
$users_name = getUserName();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: While adding `$con` in the `$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Users");` it's giving me error `unidentified variable con`

Comment: Are you sure you included the right connection file ?

Comment: I am using a function so is there something to do with it?

Comment: What if you try to access config.php directly ? Do you see the "Connection successful" string or a mysqli_connection error ?

Comment: I always get `Connection successful`

Comment: I really think that your config.php file is not include correctly. Please double check it.

Comment: I have triple checked it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135651/discussion-between-faisal1208-and-jazz).

Comment: Working like a champ :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line After sql Query

```
$sql="insert sql query";

$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Add in while loop use this one

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)
```

## updated

```
    <?php
require_once ('config.php');

$result= "SELECT * FROM Users";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$result);

$response = array();

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($response,array('Id' =>$row['Id'] ,
    'Name' =>$row['Name']

        //      add element on your array

    ));
    }
    echo json_encode(($response));

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**Put config and php file in the same folder**

Comment: While adding `$con` in the `$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Users");` it's giving me error `unidentified variable con`

Comment: add this in your config file: `$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE)or die('Unable to Connect');`
 and remove if else loop

Comment: Kindly see my `config` part in my question i have already added it

Comment: Do i have to exclude my function ?

Comment: there is no need to add your function.. but if u want u can

Comment: The problem is still there as i can find `$con` in my intellesence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135650/discussion-between-faisal1208-and-dhruv-tyagi).